# Hiding certain images on phones

Tags: html, css

I am trying to hide two images when the website goes on a mobile. I've tried multiple solutions and tries but I can't seem to get working.

Here are my code snippets

```
<li style="background-image: url(images/img_bg_1.jpg);" class="hideimg">
```

and

```
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  img.hideimg {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

Comment: Today most phones have a much larger screen.

Comment: Where's the `img` element?

Comment: **** that might be why its set as a background image ......

Comment: anyway of hiding background images

Answer (score 1):

You currently have two main issues. Firstly, your current CSS selector `img.hideimg` is looking for an `<img>` element. As you are modifying a `<li>`, you'd want to use a selector either looking for a `<li>` element like `li.hideimg` or simply look for the class regardless of what kind of element `.hideimg`.

Secondly, you are assigning a background image directly using an HTML attribute (`style=""`). Inline styles like this has a higher level of specificity than rulesets in stylesheets and style blocks, which means you will not be able to overwrite this later on (unless you use `!important`, but you don't want to go there!)

I will suggest you remove the inline styles from your HTML:

```
<li class="hideimg">
```

And then use the progressive enhancement approach to hide the image by default, and then display it for large screens (not the other way around):

```
li.hideimg {
  display: block;
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  background: none;
}
@media screen and (min-width: 600px) {
  .hideimg {
    background-image: url("https://source.unsplash.com/random/300x200");
  }
}
```

See the result in [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xt4w63u7/).

Answer (score 0):

Not img.hideimg . Because, used `<li>`. Correct usage li.hideimg or only .hideimg

Comment: let me have a try